# Identificar um clique longo com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera montei um context menu que funciona assim, quando o usuário clica com o botão direito do mouse em uma 'tr' da tabela ele se abre.

Faço assim usando jQuery:

```
// Verifica se abre o menu
$("tr").mousedown(function (e) {
  //AQUI FICA AS FUNÇÕES DO MENU
});
```

Bom, o problema é que, quando ele é aberto em um celular, não se tem o mouse.

Queria saber se tem alguma forma de identificar um clique por 2 segundos, e abrir o menu.

Então ele deverá se abrir tanto com o botão direito ou com um clique longo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ou você pode utilizar o evento [taphold](http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/) do jQuery Mobile API:

> O evento jQuery Mobile taphold desencadeia-se após um evento de toque
>   completo e sustentado (também conhecido como pressão longa).

Para seu caso ficaria mais ou menos:

```
$("tr").on( "taphold", function( event ) {
  //AQUI FICA AS FUNÇÕES DO MENU
});
```

Somente com jQuery, é possível calcular o tempo entre o `mousedown` e `mouseup`:

```js
var tempo;

$("div").mouseup(function(){
  
  // diferença entre clicar e soltar
  var total = new Date().getTime() - tempo;
  var segundos = ((total % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
  console.log(total); // total se millis
  console.log(segundos); // total em segundos
  
  if (segundos > 0){
    console.log("Oi");
  }
  
}).mousedown(function(){
  
  // set tempo ao clicar
  tempo = new Date().getTime();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Teste
</div>
```

Comment: Muito com, era isso mesmo que eu precisava, mas como vou chamar a função '$("tr").on( "taphold", function( event ) {' quando o segundos for maior que 2?

Comment: Justamente, ele trata sozinho isso @HugoBorges. Por isso editei colocando o tempo em segundo somente com jQuery :)

Comment: estou tentando fazer essa verificação, 'if (segundos > 0) {console.log("oi");}' mas não funciona, vc sabe porque?

Comment: Precisava inverter os operadores para não ficar negativo @HugoBorges. Editei a resposta :)

Comment: não estou conseguindo fazer o menu abrir com um clique longo (e tenhas mais de 1 segundo), poderia me ajudar? segue meu código https://jsfiddle.net/hugoborges/50bh9t1a/2/

Comment: @HugoBorges, notei que ele está entrando na condição normalmente, mas não acontece nada na tela. Visto que é outro assunto, sugiro que abra outra pergunta se o problema for com o menu, para não ramificar essa sua pergunta.